# Induction for an inequality

Tags: inequality, induction, recurrence-relations

Let $C_1>0,C_2>0, a>0, b>0$ be constants, let $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} C_1e^{-C_2m}=1$ and $f\leq 1$ be a function satisfying the inequality

$$f(n)\leq \sum_{m=1}^n e^{am} f(n-m) \frac{C_1}{1-C_1}e^{-C_2m} + \frac{e^{an}}{1-C_1}\left[1-\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} C_1e^{-C_2m}\right]\tag{1}$$

> I'm trying to check if there exist constants $b,C$ such that $b<a$ and $C>0$ and $f(n)\leq Ce^{bn}$ for all $n\geq 0$.

My attempt: I'm trying to see if this is true by induction. For $n=0$, $f(0)\leq C$ if $C\geq 1$. So choose any $C\geq 1$. Suppose there exists $b<a$ such that $f(m)\leq Ce^{bm}$ for all $m<n$. Using this in $(1)$, we get

\begin{align}
f(n) &\leq \sum_{m=1}^n e^{am}Ce^{b(n-m)}\frac{C_1}{1-C_1}e^{-C_2m} + \frac{e^{an}}{1-C_1}\left[1-\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} C_1e^{-C_2m}\right] \\ \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^n e^{am}Ce^{b(n-m)}\frac{C_1}{1-C_1}e^{-C_2m} + \frac{e^{an}}{1-C_1}\left[1-\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} C_1e^{-C_2m}\right] \\ \\
&= Ce^{bn}\left[\sum_{m=1}^n e^{(a-b-C_2)m}\frac{C_1}{1-C_1}+ \frac{e^{(a-b)n}}{1-C_1}\left[1-\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} C_1e^{-C_2m}\right]\right]
\end{align}

I think the induction statement is proven if we show that
$$\left[\sum_{m=1}^n e^{(a-b-C_2)m}\frac{C_1}{1-C_1}+ \frac{e^{(a-b)n}}{1-C_1}\left[1-\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} C_1e^{-C_2m}\right]\right]\leq 1 \tag{2}$$
because that would mean $f(n)\leq Ce^{bn}$. But I'm not sure how to prove that and show there exists a $b<a$ for which $(2)$ is true. Any ideas?

Comment: Your notations are too complicated. Why don't use $A=e^a$ and $c=e^{-C_2}?$ Your condition about $C_1$ and $C_2$ is simply $C_1=1-c$. What is the meaning of (1) when $n=0?$ Why don't you use $F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)z^n$ to clarify (1)? The last bracket of (1) is nothing but $(Ac)^n/(1-C_1).$

Comment: @GérardLetac  I see that you're suggesting using the generating function of $f$
 but I don't know what you mean by "use $F(z)$ to clarify $(1)$".

Comment: Your hairy (1) could be rewritten as $ F(z)\leq F(z)G(z)$ for $z>0$ and a suitable $G$ that I cannot compute since you have not told us yet the meaning of (1) for $n=0.$

Comment: @GérardLetac There is no meaning of $(1)$ for $n=0$. $(1)$ holds for $n\geq 1$. That doesn't having a bearing on showing $f(n)\leq Ce^{bn}$ for $n\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $A=e^a$, $c=e^{-C_2}$ and let us decide that (1) has a little mistake and that $m$ should vary from $0$ to $n$. We have $C_1=1-c.$ Therefore
$$f(n)\leq \frac{1-c}{c}\sum_{m=0}^n(Ac)^nf(n-m) + \frac{1}{c}(Ac)^n.$$ Assume that $f(n)\geq 0.$ As a consequence for $z>0$ and small enough we have
$$F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)z^n\leq \frac{1-c}{c}\frac{1}{1-Acz}F(z)+\frac{1}{c}\frac{1}{1-Acz}$$ or denoting $1/r=\frac{Ac^2}{2c-1}$ we have
$$(2c-1)(1-\frac{1}{r}z)F(z)\leq 1.\ \ (*)$$ At this point if your $C_2$ is too big, that is to say if $c\leq 1/2$ I cannot say anything since (*) gives no information. In the other hand, if $2c-1>0$ then
$$(2c-1)F(z)\leq \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{r}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{r^n}$$
showing that the radius of convergence $R$ of the power series $F(z)$ satisfies $R\geq r.$ This implies that $\limsup f(n)^{1/n}=\frac{1}{R}\leq \frac{1}{r}.$ In particular there exists a number $B> \frac{1}{R}$ such that $f(n)<B^n$ for all $n.$ A weaker statement is that for any $C>\frac{1}{r}$ we have  $f(n)<C^n$ except for a finite number of $n.$

Equivalently for each $b$ such that $e^b>1/r$
there exists $C_3>0$ such that $f(n)<C_3e^{bn}.$ But saying $e^b>1/r$ is saying
$b>a-2C_2+\log (2c-1).$ Therefore since $-2C_2+\log (2c-1)<0$ the interval
$$(a-2C_2+\log (2c-1),a) $$ is not empty and there exists a $b<a$ such that $f(n)<C_3e^{bn}$ as desired.

Comment: You haven't explained to us how you got the second inequality. By $F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty$, I'm guessing you mean $F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)z^n$. Sure, $\sum_{m=0}^n (Acz)^m \leq \sum_{m=0}^\infty (Acz)^m = \frac{1}{1-Acz}$. You haven't explained how you got $f(n-m)\leq F(z)$?

Comment: I have filled the missing $f(n)z^n$, thanks. About your second question, let me recall a property of the Cauchy  product $(h_n)_{n\geq 0}$ of two sequences $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ defined by $h_n=\sum_{m=0}^ng_mf_{n-m}$. With obvious notations, if the radius of  convergence $R_f$ and $R_g$ are positive then $R_h\geq \min (R_f, R_g)$ and $H(z)=F(z)G(z).$

Comment: I think you mean $H(z)\leq F(z)G(z)$ and also $m$ in the first summation of inequality $(1)$ in my question, ranges from $1$ to $n$ and not $0$ to $n$.

Comment: It is also not clear why you would want $z$ to be small enough and how small in your answer. The answer overall is not easy to understand, you may be right but without explanation it's not understandable.

Comment: No no Garfield $H=FG,$ since I was recalling a calculus fact. The $z$ is small enough means   smaller than the radius of convergence. I am sorry that my answer is obscure to you. May be you can get help from somebody else.