# Understanding radius of convergence of a power series

Tags: analysis, power-series

I'm looking at the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#:%7E:text=The%20radius%20of%20convergence%20of%20a%20power%20series%20f%20centered,called%20the%20disk%20of%20convergence.) definition of radius of convergence of a power series and have a few questions. If my power series, for $z\in \mathbb{R}$, is
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{r^n}$$
then

1. Am I correct in saying the radius of convergence $R=r$ because $f(z)$ converges if $z<r$?
2. I'd asked another question on power series [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4726046/induction-for-an-inequality) and the answer said the radius of convergence $R$ of $F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{r^n}$ is $R\geq r$ which is the opposite of what I'm thinking. May I know what is right?

Comment: Is $z$ a complex number in this context? If so, then it doesn't make sense for a complex number to be "less than" a real number since there's no canonical ordering used for complex numbers.

Comment: I'm thinking $z\in \mathbb{R}$. I shoul have mentioned that.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for pointing it out to me.

Comment: Your thinking is very correct, but slightly incomplete. Firstly, it should be $\lvert z\rvert<r$ in your first point. Then you just also need the fact that it diverges for $\lvert z\rvert>r$ and you're done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radius of convergence of a power series
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
is defined as the maximal $R>0$ such that the above series converges for $|x|<R$. In your case, $a_n=r^{-n}$, so we can check that the radius of convergence is $R=r$, as you suggest (in particular $R\geq r$, which seems to be the only thing that is needed in the argument from the question you refer to).

In short, both 1. and 2. are correct.

EDIT: in the question you refer to, they actually have something like $F(z)\leq \sum_{i=0}^\infty z^n/r^n$, so you can only deduce that the radius of convergence of $F$ is $\geq r$ (if the power series converges, then F 'converges')

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's true, in the question I referred to, there is an inequality.